# Proving Uniform Continuity on $f(x) = 3x^2 + 2x$ on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Let $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$, and let $x,y \in [0, 1]$. Choose $\delta = \dfrac\varepsilon2$, such that $|y-x| < \delta = \dfrac\varepsilon2$.
>   So, $|f(x) - f(y)| = \left|3y^2 + 2y - 3x^2 - 2x\right| = \left|3(y^2 - x^2) - 2(y-x\right)|$. We note that $|y-x| \le 1$ and $|y+x| \le 2$. So, $\left|3(y^2 - x^2) - 2(y-x)\right| < \left|2(y-x)\right|$. Thus, $|f(x) - f(y)| < 2|y-x| < \varepsilon$. Therefore, $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$ so $f(x)$ is UC on $[0,1]$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: How do you conclude $|3(y^2-x^2)-2(y-x)|<|3(y+x)(y-x)|$?

Comment: Could I possibly include y>x for ordering in order to make that inequality true?

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant, but you can take $y>x$ wlog.

Comment: $|3(y^2 - x^2) - 2(y-x)| = |3(y+x)(y-x) - 2(y-x)|$ and since $y > x$, then $|3(y+x)(y-x)| > |3(y+x)(y-x) - 2(y-x)|$

Comment: Consider $y=0.1$ and $x=0$. The inequality fails there.

Comment: Since we're in $[0,1]$, $|3(y^2-x^2) - 2(y-x)| < |2(y-x)|$, so we choose $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{2}$

Comment: A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. This is true in arbitrary metric spaces. I suggest you prove this exercise, then apply it to your specific example. That will prove more beneficial in the long-run than fiddling with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ for every such problem.

Comment: I would do that however I have to use the epsilon delta definition to prove these problems for my class

Answer (score 1):

There is a cleaner way to do the inequality above. Consider
\begin{align*}
|3(y^2-x^2)-2(y-x)|&=|3(y+x)-2||y-x|\\
&\leq |3(y+x)-2|\delta\leq (3|y+x|+2)\delta\leq8\delta
\end{align*}
Choosing $\delta=\epsilon/8$ will then suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Proving uniform continuity becomes much easier(on compact sets) if you take the derivative, and apply the mean value theorem.

Essentially, just show that $f'(x) \leq n$,  so $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<n$ for all $b,a \in S$ where the desired set is $S$. But then $f(b) - f(a) \leq \delta n$, so we just set $\delta$ to be $\frac{\epsilon}{n}$. This proves the uniform - continuity.

Here, the maximum of the derivative is $5$, so just set $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{5}$.